# How I can Use a font in asp.net server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a probleme, the font "Segoe UI" doesn't work on an other device after publishing in asp.net server, but it work on my device, So I want a solution and thank you

II searched a lot, but I didn't find any solutions (I found solutions for C#, not vb.net), and unfortunately I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use some custom font, you don't need (or have to) use code. So it does not matter if you using VB.net, or using C#.

So, the first step is to add the font file to your project.

Almost for sure, your web application should have a font folder (and if you using master pages, then this may well change a bit).

However, let's assume we only need the font on the current page.

So, let's assume we want to use a calculator LED-like font.

So, assuming you added the font to the fonts folder. Say like this:

[image]

So, right click on your font folder (create one if you don't already have one).

Then choose add existing item, change file selector to all files (*.*), and then add your font.

In this example, the font was "calculator".

So, now on a web page, we can add the font like this:

```
    <title></title>

    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
     @font-face
     {
          font-family: 'myCalculator';
          src: url('../fonts/Calculator.ttf');
     }
</style>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div style="padding:35px">

            <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="123456789" 
              style="font-size:32px;font-family:myCalculator"
               ></asp:Label>

        </div>

    </form>
```

So, above looks like this:

[image]

But, we could make the font bold, make it red, add a solid black border.

So, say this:

```
            <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="123456789" 
            style="font-size:32px;font-family:myCalculator;
                font-weight:bold;color:red;
                border-style:solid;
                border-color:black;padding:4px"        
               >
```

And now we get/see this:

[image]

So, the font I used for above example, can be found here:

https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=302